# Object destructuring in a loop

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve this without hardcoding the index?

```
  const { TargetQuantity: targetQuantity1 } = res.data.d.results[0]
  const { TargetQuantity: targetQuantity2 } = res.data.d.results[1]
  const { TargetQuantity: targetQuantity3 } = res.data.d.results[2]
  const { TargetQuantity: targetQuantity4 } = res.data.d.results[3]
```

Comment: Make an array of objects, each one with a `TargetQuantity` property.

Comment: `const targetQuantities = res.data.d.results.map(r => r.TargetQuantity)`…?

Comment: If you have multiple variables which have the same name except for a number at the end, then that's a *very* strong indication that you should be using an array.

Comment: You can use an array to store your `targetQuantities` and then use a for loop to assign the values from the `res.data.d.results`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
const results = [
  { TargetQuantity: 1 },
  { TargetQuantity: 2 },
  { TargetQuantity: 3 },
  { TargetQuantity: 4 }
];

results.map((item, i) => {

  let str ="TargetQuantity"+ (i+1) +" = item.TargetQuantity";
  eval(str)

});
```

This will create global variables `TargetQuantity1,TargetQuantity2, TargetQuantity3 ...` and so on

Answer (score 0):

```js
const results = [
  {TargetQuantity: 1},
  {TargetQuantity: 2},
  {TargetQuantity: 3},
  {TargetQuantity: 4}
];

(function (context){
  for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    context[`targetQuantity${i+1}`] = results[i].TargetQuantity;
  }
})(this);

console.log(targetQuantity3);
```

But why would you wanna do that?